# Extreme point of unit balls, the complex case

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I've been trying to determine what are the extreme point of the unit balls of $\ell^1$ and $C[0,1]$.

I think that I cracked the real case (I got for $\ell^1$: $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}\bigcup\{-e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$, and for $C[0,1]$ the constant functions $f=1$ and $f=-1$).

I had a little trouble figuring out what should be the answer in case the field is $\mathbb C$. I think it should be (for $\ell^1$) all the $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}\bigcup\{-e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}\{ie_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}\bigcup\{-ie_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$, and (for $C[0,1]$) the functions $f=1, f=-1, f=i, f=-i$. But I can also see it go to (for $\ell^1$) all the $\{ae_n:|a|=1\}$, and (for $C[0,1]$ all the constant functions $f=a$ with $|a|=1$.

I would like some guidness if possible. Knowing the right answer could help, as well as the intuition behind and maybe some tips on how to get there. Thanks!!